# In java how can I directly change another class' buttons and strings while I'm in another class

Tags: java, class, variables

I have a GridBagLayout GUI that adds Board class obj in its 0 0 cell and RightPanel obj in its  1 0 cell. What i want to do is for my GUI class to have access to the RightPanel's Strings and buttons. For starters, i'm just currently trying to change String wName, but with no success. pls help me identify what I'm doing wrong.
Note: I know this problem may sound weird to others, but I just really need to know how.

IN my GUI i'm doing this:

```
public class TheraGUI extends JFrame {
    public RightPanel rpref;

//I add this so I can call right panel
    public TheraGUI(RightPanel rpref){
        this.rpref = rpref;
    }

    public TheraGUI(){
        Board board = new Board();
        Board bref = new Board(this);
        RightPanel rp = new RightPanel();
        this.rpref.wName = "Gel"
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.setTitle("Thera");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(board);
        this.add(rp);
        this.pack();    
    }

}
```

In my RightPanel I have this:

```
public class RightPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final String imageFolderPath = "src/resources/images/";
    private Dimension dimension = new Dimension(200, 500);
    private static final String defaultImgPiece = "demigod.png";
    public JLabel wImgPic;
    public String wName;

//And here I instantiate the constructor
    public TheraGUI guiref = new TheraGUI(this);    


public RightPanel(){
    this.setPreferredSize(dimension);
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints rpc = new GridBagConstraints();

    //White's Panel
    JPanel wpanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    rpc.gridx = 0;
    rpc.gridy = 0;
    this.add(wpanel, rpc);

//   Piece Name Info   //
    wName = "Helios, the Demigod";
    JLabel wNamePiece = new JLabel(wName);
    wNamePiece.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 16));
    wNamePiece.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 0, 20);
    wpanel.add(wNamePiece, gbc);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need to have some structure to your code to eliminate uncontrolled coupling.

That aside, changing wName does not help, you need to call wNamePiece.setText(). And for this you need to have it as a member variable.

Additionally, you need to make this call within Event Dispatcher Thread. If you are not making this call within a separate thread, you are safe.